# Is it possible to pair 3 or more iPads via bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, bluetooth

Is it possible connect 3 or more iPads via bluetooth in one local network via standard iOS sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your use case is, you probably want to look at the [Gamekit documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and more specifically the peer-peer connectivity section.

[Volcore's blog here](http://volcore.limbicsoft.com/search/label/gamekit) has some useful realworld info too.

Answer (score 1):

You mean creating ad-hoc network of iPad?
I don't think thats possible. But lets wait for the big guns to throw more light on this.